# Dataflow pipeline custom transform performance decreases as more data is passed through transform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a dataflow pipeline (Java 1.9.0) which reads data from GCS does a transform then outputs into a GroupBy transform.

I have been running this pipeline in production for couple of months with no problems. But today the pipeline started taking twice the time to run. I read 600 million lines into the pipeline and pass it through transform step X. Previously step X will process row at 200k/sec but now I am noticing after 575 million rows have passed through step X the performance decreases dramatically to about 5K/second.

I added logging in Step X to see if my code is taking more time towards the end of the pipeline when >575million rows have passed through transform, But I see consistent times to what it was when pipeline was processing at 200k/sec.

Comment: Do you have a job ID?

Comment: @jkff id is 2017-09-06_01_38_26-12663151832226333140

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This job has failed due to an unusually slow BigQuery import that took over an hour, and a service-side bug that can fail a job if it is too slow in some cases: we're investigating the bug.

Try running your job with `--experiments=enable_custom_bigquery_sink` or updating your SDK to 2.0+ - this should solve the issue.

I also noticed that the pipeline structure of this job seems to be a lot more complex than it should be (it uses a very large number of similar pipeline steps where I believe many of the similar steps could have been condensed into a single step).

I would recommend posting a question on StackOverflow describing roughly what you're trying to accomplish and ask what is a simpler way to express it with Beam/Dataflow.

In particular, I suspect that the `TextIO.readAll()` transform will greatly help you (available in Beam at HEAD or in 2.2 which should be released soon) - see https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.java - as well as, potentially, the DynamicDestinations support in BigQuery (available since 2.0).

Comment: appreciate your reply

Comment: if I add `--experiments=enable_custom_bigquery_sink` would that increase the pipeline cost?

Comment: I don't think it should. It does basically the same things, as far as I'm aware. It's also the default mode in 2.0+.

Comment: per your suggestion I combined as many steps as possible into one step. Also added `--experiments=shuffle_mode=service` flag per GCP support, Can you please take a quick look at the pipeline id `2017-09-11_13_44_37-4123012754755934242`. Thanks

Comment: Hmm, I found another performance issue in this pipeline: it's using quite a large value as a side input (about 600MB), and what's more surprising, using it as an Iterable. Is that expected? How do you use the side input: do you iterate over all the 600MB of it on every element in the Filter step?

Comment: Yes that side input is what I used to create a Graph data structure. Then I pass input through the graph.  In the filter step graph is a static variable so once its populated other runs on DoFn just use that populated graph &  don't create from scratch and don't loop over the side input. You can read more about use case here https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/349351/moving-from-batch-to-streaming-architecture-using-a-graph-datastructure,

Comment: Okay. I don't have time to analyze the algorithm in detail but sounds like you have something going. Let me know if the job fails again.

Comment: So the above pipeline 2017-09-11_13_44_37-4123012754755934242 did end up failing. it probably fused together all the steps into one. Last time this happened I increased node type from standard4 to highmem4 and it worked.

Comment: Running the pipeline on `highmem4` did succeed `2017-09-11_17_13_13-11940612306184596563`. I think one of the reason pipeline runs slow is because I have 30 Text.IO.Read steps. If I can merge all Text.IO.Read into one step using glob patterns I think that will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46167405/textio-read-gcs-folders-into-pipeline-with-past-30-days-date-as-name

Comment: Also I am running `2017-09-11_17_13_13-11940612306184596563`  with `experiments=shuffle_mode=service`. Can you please confirm shuffle service is being used. Thanks.

Comment: The reason is, most likely, not the number of read steps, but the number of write steps. The workers are OOMing because they are writing to a large number of files at the same time and the file write buffers take up memory. We have safeguards against this when writing to a large number of destinations in 1 write step, but not when a large number of separate write steps are fused together. Is it possible to change your code to use the DynamicDestinations APIs in the file and bigquery sinks to write to multiple destinations, and thus reduce the number of write steps?

Comment: Regarding your last job: hmm, no, I don't see it using the shuffle service; I don't see the parameter even listed in command-line arguments.